# How to sort this Map<String, List<class>>

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary

I have this Map, which contains names, last names, and other personal information , for exmaple:

```
jhon:[doe];

ann:[devil]
```

What I want is to order them alphabetically, but this kind of structure is new to me.
How can I order them alphabetically? Here my code

```
 private String uid;
    private String username;
    private String fullName;
    private String name;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    private Map<String, List<PorticoProfile>> profiles;

    public Map<String, List<PorticoProfile>> getProfiles() {
        if (profiles == null) {
            profiles = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        }
        return profiles;
    }

    public void setProfiles(Map<String, List<PorticoProfile>> profiles) {
        this.profiles = profiles;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
        if (fullName.contains(" ")){
            String[] nameParts = fullName.split(" ");
            this.name = nameParts[0];
            this.lastname = nameParts[1];
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        final String BREAK = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("uid: ").append(this.uid).append(BREAK);
        sb.append("username: ").append(this.username).append(BREAK);
        sb.append("fullname: ").append(this.fullName).append(BREAK);
        sb.append("email: ").append(this.email).append(BREAK);
        sb.append("phone: ").append(this.phone).append(BREAK);
        if (this.getProfiles().size() > 0){
            sb.append("profiles: ").append(this.profiles.keySet().stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", "))).append(BREAK);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: by using `TreeMap` you can get sorted values based on Key in Map.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS according to both , due to sometimes we have to do the search by name andothers by last name

Comment: @Amogh it can´t be done with the code I already have?

Comment: @Tony, check answer given by Friso. You don't have to change anything. In `toString()` you only have to create `TreeMap` using `profiles` so that its sorted then go for append operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TreeMap` - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html

`LinkedHashMap` will preserve the order in which you add data to the Map, `TreeMap` will keep it sorted based on the key, which in your case is `String` i.e. the name

```
Map<String, List<PorticoProfile>> profiles = new TreeMap<>();;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should checkout another interface: the SortedMap (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html)

```
    Map<String, Object> m = new HashMap<>();
    m.put("john", "doe");
    m.put("ann", "devil");

    SortedMap<String, Object> s = new TreeMap<>(m);
    s.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Map<String, List<MyClass>> sorted = map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getKey)) // sort by key
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```